# Read column, select hyperlink, and then paste link name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of data. I want to select the cells that contain a hyperlink and print just the values of those cells.

I have the following code to extract the hyperlink. I want if there is a link in cell A1 called "hello", it doesn't print the link itself, but prints "hello".

```
Sub ExtractHL()

Dim HL As Hyperlink

For Each HL In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks

    HL.Range.Offset(0, 1).Value = HL.Address

Next

End Sub
```

The other idea I just had was to say that if a cell in a row DOESN'T contain a hyperlink, then to delete that row, but I'm not sure how to negate the "for each HL in sheet" line.

Comment: Even though I figured out my original question, I'm still not sure on the answer to my add on part (i.e instead of selecting hyperlinks and printing them, how would I delete all values that don't contain a link). Does anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: The second part would require you to create a range, loop through it, and see if a hyperlink exists in that row. If not, delete entire row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the "HL.Address" to HL.Range pastes that range.